# Is h(x) is strictly increasing?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f : (0, \infty) \to(0, \infty)$ be a strictly decreasing function. Consider 
$$h(x)=\frac{f\left(\frac{x}{1+x}\right)}{1+f\left(\frac{x}{1+x}\right)}$$
Which one of the following is always true?

$A)$ $h$ is strictly decreasing

$B)$ $h$ is strictly increasing

$C)$ $h$ is strictly decreasing at first and then strictly increasing

$D)$ $h$ is strictly increasing at first and then strictly decreasing

My attempt:  Take  $h(x)$, $\displaystyle 1 + f\left(\frac{x}{1+x}\right) =f\left(\frac{x}{1+x}\right)$, here I take take $\displaystyle f\left(\frac{x}{1+x}\right) = x$, and $\displaystyle h(x) = \frac{x}{x+1}$,from here i can conclude that $h$ is  strictly increasing.

Is my answer is correct?

Comment: No, take for example $f(x)=1/x$ and this gives $h(x) = (1+x)/(1+2x)$ which means that $h(1) = 2/3 > 3/5 = h(2)$.

Comment: but 1/0 is not exist  @ skyking

Comment: That's not a problem since $f:(0,\infty)\to(0,\infty)$ which means that $f(x)$ doesn't have to be defined for $x=0$.

Comment: why down votes...@skyking

Comment: I don't know. I see little reason in downvoting this or closing this. Who has downvoted it we cannot tell, but the ones that has voted to put this on hold is known and should be able to answer why this was closed.

Answer (score 5):

The map $\varphi\colon [0,+\infty) \to [0,1)$ defined by
$$
\varphi(t) := \frac{t}{1+t}\,,
\qquad (t\geq 0)
$$
is strictly increasing.

You can check that
$$
h(x) = \varphi(f(\varphi(x))),
\qquad x > 0,
$$
i.e. $h=\varphi\circ f\circ\varphi$.
But the composition of two strictly increasing functions is a strictly increasing function, whereas the composition of a strictly increasing function with a strictly decreasing one is a strictly decreasing function.
Hence $h$ is strictly decreasing.

Comment: @ Rigel,,thanks a lots,,,for beautiful answer

Comment: There's a slight error here however, the function $f$ is strictly **decreasing** (this makes $h$ strictly decreasing). Also I think you should exclude $0$ from the domain and range of $\varphi$.

Comment: Yes, sure. I was assuming $f$ increasing.